# ASP.net MVC can't access ajax data in the controller function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax, x-editable

I use x-editable and try to post date to my controller

x-editable code is

`<span class="editable editable-click" title="" data-type="select" data-value="1" data-pk="2" data-url="http://localhost:58250/api/updateeffortitems/save" data-title="Work group" data-source="[{ value: 1, text: 'Project'},{ value: 2, text: 'Service'},{ value: 3, text: 'Process'},{ value: 4, text: 'Training'},{ value: 5, text: 'Others'}]" data-original-title="Project">Project</span>`

now i try to access posted data in the following controller

```
Public Class UpdateEffortItemsController
    Inherits ApiController
    Public Function save(pk As Integer, value As String) As String

        Dim db As New RA_SQLEntities

        Dim row As Ra_activity_log
        row = db.Ra_activity_log.Where(Function(XX) XX.Activity_log_key = pk).SingleOrDefault()
        row.Comment = value
        db.SaveChanges()

        Return "done"

    End Function

End Class
```

and i got the following error

`{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:58250/api/updateeffortitems/save'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'UpdateEffortItems' that matches the request."}`

i know the controller function must have 2 params and the ajax url didnt have these params .. but when i add the params to ajax url that mean the params equel to static value and not able to change

what should i do?

Comment: you need to add [HttpPost] above to the method. So it can call on post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class for the action parameters. Here is what the ASP.NET MVC doku says:

> By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:
>
> - If the parameter is a “simple” type, Web API tries to get the value from the URI. Simple types include the .NET primitive types (int,
>     bool, double, and so forth), plus TimeSpan, DateTime, Guid, decimal,
>     and string, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from
>     a string. (More about type converters later.)
> - For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Code might look like this (I'm not a VB coder):

```
Public Class XEditablePost
    Public Property Pk() As Integer
    Public Property Value() As String
End Class

....

Public Function save(payload As XEditablePost) As String
    ....
End Function
```

Hope that helps.